# Non trivial (seemingly) StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, crash

Our crash logging system shows a crash and I can't understand how does it happen. The user inputs are unknown. I've added logging, but results will be visible only after the next release, ~2 weeks.

How can the code below throw the next exception:

```
Crashes with java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException length=0; index=1
```

Not because of a concurrency issue? In other words, what might be the situation in which it crashes and how to avoid it (without wrapping it into `try-catch`)? What could be the case if it's a concurrency issue (I don't see one but maybe I'm wrong)?

```
private String contactName; // has getter and setter

public String getFirstSymbol() {
  String firstSymbol = "";
  String trimmed = contactName.trim();
  if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(trimmed)) { // TextUtils.isEmpty is Android method: return str == null || str.length() == 0;
    String[] parts = trimmed.toUpperCase().split("\\s+");
    firstSymbol = parts[0].substring(0, 1); // crashes here:
  }
  return firstSymbol;
 }
```

There are ~100 crashes on 7 devices in the last week.

Here is the stack trace

```
  Fatal Exception: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=1
  at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1971)
  at my.app.model.Contact.getFirstSymbol(Contact.java:256)
  at my.app.ui.AvatarView.bind(AvatarView.java:73)
  at my.app.viewholder.CallLogViewHolder.bind(CallLogViewHolder.java:50)
  at my.app.viewholder.CallLogViewHolder.bind(CallLogViewHolder.java:23)
  at my.app.ContactListAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ContactListAdapter.java:68)
  at my.app.ContactListAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ContactListAdapter.java:25)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onCreateViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.getItemCount(RecyclerView.java:6781)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6823)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5752)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6019)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3641)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4194)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20964)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20964)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
  at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1775)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20964)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
  at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:142)
  at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.findFirstDependency(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:142)
  at com.google.android.material.appbar.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:41)
  at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1556)
  at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:888)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20964)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20964)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
  at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:142)
  at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.findFirstDependency(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:142)
  at com.google.android.material.appbar.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:41)
  at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1556)
  at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:888)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20964)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20964)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20964)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20964)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20964)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:955)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20964)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3092)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2779)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1863)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8072)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

Comment: what is `value` of `fieldString` could you provide some sample inputs?

Comment: I'm not sure your problem is reproducible.  So, you should give us inputs for which this is happening.

Comment: The issue is that it's something that comes from our crash logging system. The inputs are not shown in it. I've added logging, but results will be only there in a couple of weeks.

Did I got you right that this code looks fine overall without any obvious flaws?

Comment: Basically, the string contains some Contact's name from Android phones

Comment: You could try posting the entire stacktrace

Comment: `String trimmed = "\n S ";` you have `string` something like that

Comment: can you show data of `contactName.trim()`

Comment: @Scary, I doubt it'll help but I've added it.

Comment: @Akash, thanks, just run the unit test on the suggested string, works as expected - returns "S"

Comment: @Akash, the same thing as above - I don't have the inputs. If I had them, it would be obvious.

Comment: @Gaket see a crash https://onlinegdb.com/ryt0-C55N

Comment: You can **easily find out** what the input that causes the problem is.  Modify your code to 1) catch the exception, 2) print out the value of `trimmed`, 3) rethrow the exception.   OR ... set a breakpoint.

Comment: getting exception for the input string " "

Comment: @Akash, you set the value for internal, method-scoped variable. However, in the given snippet your case is impossible, as the `trimmed` string is actually trimmed. Here is your updated example: https://onlinegdb.com/H1zYmAccE And it works as expected.

Comment: @StephenC, thanks. However, I've already done it. The error happens in Android app and the next release will be in a couple of weeks. So not, it's not so easy. There is ~1 mln users and I don't know whose input gets to this result.

Comment: Have you tried testing with unicode?

Comment: @ArunKumarMN, are you sure that's the exact code as above? I have such a test and it passes.

Comment: @Gaket finally reproduce your string has only `\n` see here https://onlinegdb.com/SkGmBA9qV

Comment: @ScaryWombat, I've tried to play with tabs and other space-like symbols (\u0009) with no luck

Comment: @AkashShah, you are missing the  if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(trimmed)) condition. That's basically  return str == null || str.length() == 0. If you add it, it will pass. Here is the example: https://onlinegdb.com/HkNlLCc5E

Comment: well i tried this  

" ".trim().toUpperCase().split("\\s+")[0].substring(0,1)

Comment: @ArunKumarMN yes, but that's not the same as the code in the question. Here is your updated example: https://onlinegdb.com/HkNlLCc5E

Comment: @Gaket once your update code goes to release, don't forget to update your answer with the input's that cause this issue

Answer (score 2):

There is no thread-safety / concurrency issue here.  The only value that this method *potentially* shares with other threads is the value of `contactName`.  That is a `String` reference.  `String` is immutable.  The other values that this method derives from the (potentially) shared immutable `String` are all thread-confined.

Apart from that, I am baffled.  The `trim` should remove any leading or trailing character that `\s+` would match.  And the `!isEmpty` guard eliminates the possibility of an empty string.  So the `parts` array *should* have at least 1 element, and the first element *should* have at least one character.

But the exceptions seem to be saying differently.

So this leaves "alternative" explanations that one would normally dismiss as ridiculous:

- Maybe this is occurring on a platform with a broken JIT compiler.
- Maybe this is occurring on a platform that has a bug in `String` or `Pattern`.
- Maybe it is a hardware problem.
- Maybe there is a version of your app out there whose compiled code doesn't match the source code you are looking at.

None of these "alternative" explanations give you any way forward.  So, if you don't find a better explanation, I suggest that you surround this offending code with a `try { ... } catch` and attempt to log the length and contents of the `contactName` string that trigger the problem.  Include this in the next release, and if / when you start getting failures, be prepared to ship a minor release with a real fix.  Alternatively, just treat this as if the user entered an empty contact name ... or something like that.

Comment: Yep, I had the same reasoning for the code correctness, just wanted to be sure. Thanks, will wait a day or two if smbd had a similar issue, but this looks like the answer.